Was there ever a case of אשת יפת תואר
I am curious if there is a recorded case of an אשת יפת תואר actually being taken in Tanach or from Chazal?

https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.21a.18?lang=bi&with=all

Wife of David, who was the mother of Avshalom and Tamar

@Sholom Thanks for the marei makom.
